# Save images in external storage from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to download images from parse database table and store all the images in a external memory folder. Is it possible ? If yes , how ??

Comment: What do you want to know actually? How to download images or how to save them in SDCard?

Comment: @HamidShatu I need to save the images to SDCard !!

Comment: so you downloaded the image successfully and now you just want to know how to save in SDCard, am I right?

Comment: @HamidShatu Sir, read my initial question !! I need to save images in a folder after downloading it. So, the there are two questions, first to download and then to save images. I want both the answers .. Do you have any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible. But you need to follow some steps:

-Start downloading the image Url from your Parse object:

```
String url=yourParseObject.getParseFile("Image").getUrl();
```

-Now pass that url to this function:

```
public static Drawable loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);//Your imageView in the layout 
        AsyncImageLoader async=new AsyncImageLoader();

        Drawable cachedImage = async.loadDrawable(
                url, new ImageCallback() {
                    public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable,
                            String imageUrl) {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                    }
                });
        imageView.setImageDrawable(cachedImage);
        return cachedImage;
    }
```

-If you want to save that in SD Card instead of ImageView, export that inside of the method (Drawable imageDrawable,String imageUrl) in drawable or bitmap form.

Hope it helps!

Comment: -For better image management, try to use this library: 
https://github.com/square/picasso
For more information take a look this link: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

you can do that just you need to write code for download image from url and for url you can get using ParseFile.getUrl() and for downloading file you can check this tutorial
http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can get download image from `parse.com` in bitmap then store this bitmap as image in your file directory as you want.

Refer this
[android-parse-com-image-download-tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-image-download-tutorial/)