# how to display data in parse objects to recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am developing an android app. for that I have created a table "movies" in parse.com with columns title, cast,poster release date, etc.
I want to display it in a recycler view or card view. including images.
how can i do that...?

how to display the content inside parse object...?

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Movies");
    //query.whereEqualTo("status", "true");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("title", "movie_list " + parseObjects.size() + " title");
            } else {
                Log.d("title", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code and it worked:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;
        private final TextView textView1;
        private final ImageView posterimg;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");



                }
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            posterimg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.posterimg);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
        public TextView getTextView1() {
            return textView1;
        }
        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return posterimg;
        }
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewSampleViewHolder)

    /**
     * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
     *
     * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used by RecyclerView.
     */
    public On_Theatre_nearest_Adapter(List<ParseObject> dataSet,int s) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        ss=s;
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnCreateViewHolder)
    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnCreateViewHolder)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnBindViewHolder)
    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view
        // with that element



        String strtitle;
        String strdirector;
        if(mDataSet.get(position).get("title").toString().length()<=16)
        {
             strtitle = mDataSet.get(position).get("title").toString();
        }else {
             strtitle = mDataSet.get(position).get("title").toString().substring(0, 16)+"...";
        }
        viewHolder.getTextView().setText(strtitle);
        if(mDataSet.get(position).get("director").toString().length()<=18)
        {
            strdirector = mDataSet.get(position).get("director").toString();
        }else {
            strdirector = mDataSet.get(position).get("director").toString().substring(0, 14)+"...";
        }
        viewHolder.getTextView1().setText(strdirector);

        ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile)mDataSet.get(position).get("poster");
        applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // data has the bytes for the resume
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                   viewHolder.getImageView().setImageBitmap(bmp);


                } else {
                    // something went wrong


             }
                }
            });

        }




        // END_INCLUDE(recyclerViewOnBindViewHolder)

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
           /* Log.d("title", "Error: " + mDataSet.size());
            if(mDataSet.size()==0)
            {return 5;}else
            return mDataSet.size();*/
            //int s=mDataSet.size();
            return  ss;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to get your object's attributes. So when you have done your query:

```
            List<Score> scores=new ArrayList<Score>();

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException exception) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.size(); i++) {
                            String id=scoreList.get(i).getObjectId()
                            String attribute0=scoreList.get(i).get("attribute0");
                            String attribute1=scoreList.get(i).get("attribute1");
                            String attribute2=scoreList.get(i).get("attribute2");
                            Score score = new Score (id,attribute0,attribute1,attribute2);
                            scores.add(score);    
                        }

                    }
            } });
```

Finally, you will have a List of Scores with your Parse objects added.
Hope it helps!

Comment: OK, take a look my old post in other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29468894/2606290

Comment: OK, try to mark positive my solution if it helps you, please! @Harshakrishna.K